# In Google Guava (Java), how to bulk set values for ArrayTable?

Tags: java, guava

I have a two dimensional array of data, e.g., `V[][]`, that I want to bulk set on an [ArrayTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html) instance.

Must I repeatedly call `ArrayTable.put(R rowKey, C columnKey, V value)`?

I cannot find a suitable constructor/static create helper or method, e.g., `putAll(V[][] valueArr)`.

Please advise.

Comment: What would the row and column keys be? The indices in the arrays? You would simply need 2 nested loops. I doubt Guava has anything to help you with that.

Comment: @JBNizet: The method `V set(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, V value)` proves that the row and column keys are not needed to set a value for `ArrayTable`.

Answer (score 2):

There is not such a constructor.

Your best option is:

```
ArrayTable table = ArrayTable.create(
    ContiguousSet.create(Range.closedOpen(0, v.length), 
                       DiscreteDomain.integers()), 
    ContiguousSet.create(Range.closedOpen(0, v[0].length), 
                       DiscreteDomain.integers()));
for(int i = 0 ; i < v.length ; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < v[i].length ; ++j) {
        table.set(i, j, v[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no help in guava, as @JBNizet say, because the library can't know what you want to use as keys.

You can use 2 nested loops as @JBNizet say or you can create your own [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) implementation that wraps your array and then call putAll method to copy your new table to the ArrayTable.

You don't need to implement every method on Table, you may throw UnsupportedOperationException on methods that otherwise should alter the content.